# How to merge 2 bzip2'ed files?

Tags: compression, hadoop, bzip2

I want to merge 2 bzip2'ed files. I tried appending one to another: `cat file1.bzip2 file2.bzip2 > out.bzip2` which seems to work (this file decompressed correctly), but I want to use this file as a Hadoop input file, and I get errors about corrupted blocks.

What's the best way to merge 2 bzip2'ed files without decompressing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling concatenated bzip is fixed on trunk, or should be: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4012.  There are examples of it working: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-477?focusedCommentId=12871993&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_12871993  Make sure you're running a recent version of Hadoop and you should be fine.

Comment: Bzipped files are split correctly, but I still can't figure out how to run map task on concatenated files. (But after decompressing all of them, then `cat`, then compressing this big input file works)

Answer (score 1):

You could compress (well, store) them both into a new bz2? It'd mean you'd have to do 3 decompressions to get the contents of the 2 archives, but might work with your scenario.

Comment: This is very nice idea, much better if bzip2 would be smart, and only 1 decompression would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I came upon it right now, so, if anyone else searches for this, this is what I found to join multiple bz2 files in HDFS into one whithout using the local filesystem. This can be used for any text file also.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input foo \
-output foo_merged \
-mapper /bin/cat \
-reducer /bin/cat
```

This joins all the files in folder `foo` and writes a single file (*part-00000*) to folder `foo_merged`.

You can use wildcards for the input folder or use as many `-input` as you need to include all the files that are going to be joined.

The output file will be uncompressed. If you want the output also compressed in bz2, you should specify these two options:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D mapred.output.compress=true \
-D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec \
-input foo \
-output foo_merged \
-mapper /bin/cat \
-reducer /bin/cat
```

Replacing the BZip2Codec for whichever you want to use.

More info [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html).

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't necessary have to merge files to use them as Hadoop input:

- consider `file_name*` - a pattern;
- `file_name_1,file_name_2` - list of inputs.

And Hadoop will handle it.

Otherwise you can use streaming of the Hadoop to merge them (with decompression).

You could produce list of files by pattern like:

`FILES_LIST="'ls -m template*.bz2'"`

`INPUT_FILE="'echo $FILES_LIST | tr -d ' ' '"`

inner `'` quotes should be different. You can pass `$INPUT_FILE` as a variable to your script via CLI.

Also consider the [CombineFileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html) class as InputFormat.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem arises when you have couple thousands of compressed files of 1MB each, and you don't want to load them to HDFS, but to have a one big file that you can load.

Comment: `lbzcat part* | lbzcat -z > output_file`

Comment: My last comment does merge of files, but hadoop is unable to read them fully afterwards.